# Replace Part of QuantityArray

Tags: replacement, list-manipulation

I can't figure out how to replace a part of a quantity array.  I have:

```
executionList // Dimensions
{65, 7}
```

where each row is a QuantityArray:

```
executionList[[1]]
    QuantityArray[
StructuredArray`StructuredData[{
  7}, {{"EQR", 10000, 56.79706947887168, 1, "Buy", 176, "MOO"}, {
   "DimensionlessUnit", "USDollars", "USDollars", "DimensionlessUnit",
     "DimensionlessUnit", "DimensionlessUnit", 
    "DimensionlessUnit"}, {{1}}}]]
```

I want to replace the sixth "column" of this array (which is dimensionless), with a list of integers of length 65:

```
TransactionQty
{176, -346, -171, 510, 164, 162, 164, 161, -984, -157, -152, 624, \
149, 146, -590, 286, -284, -140, -140, 562, 141, -418, -134, -135, \
-127, -123, -123, -121, 1022, 125, 125, 130, 133, 129, 123, 122, 136, \
132, -1449, -151, 505, 175, 170, 159, 179, 190, 194, 191, -1625, \
-186, -184, -178, 930, 183, 185, -775, 425, 199, 165, -754, -162, \
487, -295, 284, 135}
```

The obvious attempt fails:

```
executionList[[All, 6]] = TransactionQty
Set::partd: Part specification executionList[[All,6]] is longer than depth of object.
```

I have tried ReplacePart, Riffle, Table,...but I cant find the correct formulation!

Answer (score 1):

I think the solution may be:

```
x = Normal[executionList];
x[[All, 6]] = TransactionQty;
executionList=QuantityArray[x];
```